# Remove textbox, hr and text when remove button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the *via textbox*, *remove button* and *horizontal line* when the **Remove** button is clicked (as seen in the image below).

[image]

I've tried the following so far but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Remove waypoints
    $(".remove-waypoint-button").click(function() {
        $(this).parent.closest('input').remove();
        $(this).parent.closest('hr').remove();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gs7efdj8/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead of [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Use

```
// Remove waypoints
$(".remove-waypoint-button").click(function () {
    $(this).prev('input').remove();
    $(this).prev('hr').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m35Lb60m/)

However I would recommend you to wrap input and button in a div, then you can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to remove all at once. Here's an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Remove waypoints
  $(".remove-waypoint-button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="waypoints">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via" />
    <label class="remove-waypoint-button">Remove</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via" />
    <label class="remove-waypoint-button">Remove</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it was just about to post. +1 correct answer

Comment: I think it's working as anticipated. It's hard to tell because they all are identical visually. But type in one, and then click 'remove'. you'll notice that it does get removed.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to improve your mark up by grouping similar fields.

This improves the script too.

I hope this is what you expected.

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".remove-waypoint-button").on("click", function() {
      $(this).parent(".container").remove();
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="waypoints">
  <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via">
  <hr>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via">
    <label class="remove-waypoint-button">Remove</label>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via">
    <label class="remove-waypoint-button">Remove</label>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint input-lg" placeholder="Via">
    <label class="remove-waypoint-button">Remove</label>
    <hr>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

closest() works on the parent of the element. hr and input are not parent of label.
thanks